# How to read CSV in chunks of 3 line & Jump lines in chunks, if condition unsatisfied using PYTHON?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a big CSV file (~20000 lines) like given below. Each line corresponds to data/Second. So 60 lines indicate data from 60 seconds.

I am looking for a stable set of data between three lines. So if COLUMN H data is not varying by more than 5, for consecutive 3 lines, I can call it stable. (297,319,326 varying more than 5, hence unstable).

If varying more than 5, my code should check for another set of 3 lines AFTER  14 SECONDS(after 14 lines). (362,362,355 not varying more than 5, hence stable & one data snapshot is ready), and this continues till the last line, checking for more data snapshots.

Each stable value is then averaged and printed into .TXT file for analysis.

A,B,C,D,E,F,G,**H**,I,J,K,L
1) FALSE,470,496,,,0,67,**297**,341,"3,701","61,216",0
2) FALSE,464,497,,,0,67,**319**,341,"3,701","61,216",0
3) FALSE,460,498,,,0,67,**326**,348,"4,599","61,216",0
4) FALSE,459,500,,,0,67,**341**,348,"4,599","61,216",0
...
...
11) FALSE,460,502,,,0,67,**375**,348,"4,599","61,216",0
12) TRUE,461,503,,,0,67,**350**,348,"4,599","61,216",0
13) TRUE,463,504,,,0,67,**355**,348,"5,479","61,216",0
14) TRUE,467,505,,,0,67,**362**,348,"5,479","61,216",0
15) TRUE,470,507,,,0,67,**362**,348,"5,479","61,216",0
16) TRUE,472,508,,,1,67,**355**,355,"5,479","61,216",0

My code:(PYTHON 3.5)

`

```
import csv  
with open ('ABC.csv','r+') as csvfile:  
  reader=csv.reader(csvfile)  
  ROWCOUNT=0;
  for row in reader:  
    ROWCOUNT=ROWCOUNT+1  
    if row[7] in (max(ROWCOUNT,ROWCOUNT+1,ROWCOUNT+2) -min(ROWCOUNT,ROWCOUNT+1,ROWCOUNT+2) < 10:  
      average=avg(ROWCOUNT,ROWCOUNT+1,ROWCOUNT+2)  
    else:  
      ..  
      ...
```

`

My code didn't work at all, so as the logic.

SOMEONE PLEASE SUGGEST HOW TO CODE THIS USING PYTHON.

Answer (score 0):

As the CSV file is quite small (only ~20.000 lines) you can read it into memory and process it there:

```
import csv  
with open ('ABC.csv') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    data = [row for row in reader]
for i in range(0,len(data)-2,14):
    sample = int(data[i][7]), int(data[i+1][7]), int(data[i+2][7])
    if min(sample) >= max(sample)-5:
        average = sum(sample)/3
        print(average)
```